# Is there a way to keep the hash in a url when using Auth0 and Google?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, auth0

I'm using Auth0 to protect a website. When I send someone a link like `mywebsite.com/home#subtitle`, I want them to log in, and then see the `#subtitle` section immediately (this is just plain HTML: `<a id="subtitle">Subtitle</a>`).

This works with Auth0 if the user logs in with an email address and password. But if they choose "Google" (currently the only social provider I'm supporting), the `#subtitle` part is lost when they transfer from the username to the password screen.

This is what they see first (notice how the `#subtitle` is still present in the browser):

[image: Choosing login mechanism]

Then they choose Google and see this:

[image: Enter email]

Ok, the `#subtitle` is still in the browser. Now they enter their email address and transition to the password screen:

[image: Enter password]

The `#subtitle` has gone and when they continue, they are eventually redirected to `https://mywebsite.com/home` instead of `https://mywebsite.com/home#subtitle`.

Is there a way of avoiding this or is this just the way Google works? I can't capture the `#subtitle` before redirecting because I'm redirecting server-side and the `#subtitle` isn't sent to the server (as far as I can see).

Answer (score 1):

Hash fragments are a client side concept and you can't rely on server side tech to maintain them for you. One of the consequences of using server side web technologies is that you will get this type of usability problem:

- Server side security can conflict with attempts to use modern web technologies client side
- Potential problems in areas such as abrupt session expiry and losing data / location
- Potential problems in areas that use temporary cookies, such as back navigation after login

With client side tech such as the OIDC Client library you would just write a couple of lines of code before and after login, as in [my code sample](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample1/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts):

```
// Triggering a login redirect
const data = {
  hash: location.hash,
};
await this._userManager.signinRedirect({state: JSON.stringify(data)});

// Processing a login response
const user = await this._userManager.signinRedirectCallback();
const data = JSON.parse(user.state);
history.replaceState({}, document.title, data.hash);
```

With server side tech it might still be possible to solve your problem, but you need to structure your code to initiate logins from Javascript. The code for this is likely to be tricky / complicated though.